# Alternative to EXCEPT in MERGE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query to merge data from my STG table into my Data table and I want to exclude any data from the STG table which exists exactly in the Data table. I wrote the below code which does what I need but the EXCEPT statement causes massive reads on the data table. Is there any alternatives I could try to improve performance?

```
    MERGE INTO Table AS Target
USING
( /*EXCEPT STATEMENT REMOVES ANY ROWS WHICH HAVE BEEN MODIFIED, BUT NONE OF THE COLUMNS WHICH CHANGED WERE BROUGHT OVER*/
   SELECT    TimesheetEntryID
            ,UserID
            ,StartDateTime
            ,EndDateTime
            ,TimesheetTaskTypeID
            ,TaskID



    FROM Table_STG
EXCEPT
    SELECT   TimesheetEntryID
            ,UserID
            ,StartDateTime
            ,EndDateTime
            ,TimesheetTaskTypeID
            ,TaskID


    FROM Table

) AS Source

ON Target.TimesheetEntryID = Source.TimesheetEntryID

    WHEN MATCHED



    THEN

        UPDATE SET  Target.TimesheetEntryID = Source.TimesheetEntryID,
                    Target.UserID = Source.UserID,
                    Target.StartDateTime = Source.StartDateTime,
                    Target.EndDateTime = Source.EndDateTime,
                    Target.TimesheetTaskTypeID = Source.TimesheetTaskTypeID,
                    Target.TaskID = Source.TaskID



    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN

    INSERT (
                 TimesheetEntryID
                ,UserID
                ,StartDateTime
                ,EndDateTime
                ,TimesheetTaskTypeID
                ,TaskID


            )

    VALUES  (   
                 Source.TimesheetEntryID
                ,Source.UserID
                ,Source.StartDateTime
                ,Source.EndDateTime
                ,Source.TimesheetTaskTypeID
                ,Source.TaskID

            );
```

Comment: "Does what I need".  That's nice.  The code knows what you want to do, but a person reading the answer does not.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  Also, provide an appropriate database tag.

Comment: The results are fine, my question is regarding using EXCEPTS and whether there is any alternatives performance wise. Just trying to understand the best approach really.

Comment: You can use not in or not exists condition

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `not in` or `not exists`

**Not In**

```
SELECT    TimesheetEntryID
        ,UserID
        ,StartDateTime
        ,EndDateTime
        ,TimesheetTaskTypeID
        ,TaskID

FROM Table_STG where (TimesheetEntryID ,UserID ,StartDateTime ,EndDateTime 
,TimesheetTaskTypeID ,TaskID) not in
(SELECT   TimesheetEntryID ,UserID ,StartDateTime ,EndDateTime ,TimesheetTaskTypeID 
,TaskID from table);
```

**Not Exists**

```
SELECT    TimesheetEntryID
        ,UserID
        ,StartDateTime
        ,EndDateTime
        ,TimesheetTaskTypeID
        ,TaskID

FROM Table_STG STG where (TimesheetEntryID ,UserID ,StartDateTime ,EndDateTime 
,TimesheetTaskTypeID ,TaskID) not exitst
(SELECT 1 from table where TimesheetEntryID = STG.TimesheetEntryID  ,UserID = 
STG.UserID ,StartDateTime = STG.StartDateTime
,EndDateTime = STG.EndDateTime ,TimesheetTaskTypeID = STG.TimesheetTaskTypeID ,TaskID 
= STG.TaskID)
```